# Get row values from foreign key MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, multiple-tables

This may sound simple and dumb but how can I get the values of a `foreign` key from a table and displaying it?

I have a table named "`subjects`" which contains different school subjects and one column of it is a `foreign` key referencing from table named "`faculty`".

```
TABLE subjects
___________________________________
| sub_id | sub_faculty | sub_desc |
|    1   |      2      | PHYSICS  |
|    2   |      3      |   MATH   |
|    3   |      4      | HISTORY  |
|________|_____________|__________|

TABLE faculty
________________________
| fac_id |  fac_name   |
|    2   |    John     |
|    3   |    Mark     |
|    4   |   Johnny    |
|________|_____________|
```

I firstly wanted to check if data exist in the "`subject`" table and then proceed on displaying the row values of the `foreign key`.

I have this not so working query as displays both `JOHN` and `JOHNNY`. I was using `LIKE` as it will be for the search feature of the system so hopefully you can help me out on this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM subject, faculty 
WHERE subject.sub_desc = 'PHYSICS' 
  AND subject.sub_year = '4' 
  AND faculty.fac_name LIKE '%JOHN%' 
GROUP BY faculty.fac_id
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? to display faculty information for a given subject?

Comment: Right about that, I want the results to display the row in the table subject and instead of the foreign key, the row values inside the foreign key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM subject s
join faculty f 
  on s.sub_faculty = f.fac_id
WHERE s.sub_desc = 'PHYSICS' 
  AND s.sub_year = '4' 
  AND f.fac_name LIKE '%JOHN%'
```